# Error with adding all files with git

Tags: git, continuous-integration, file-permissions, travis-ci, git-add

I have tried to use git add -A to add all of my files to commit in the past, but now, it does not work anymore.

When I perform the command, the console prints out:

```
fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files on branch master
```

Any input on why this could be happening? Could this be a file permissions issue?

Some extra information: this is being built on Travis-CI.

Comment: Can you add the output of `git status` and `git config -l` to your question. It might help reproduce the issue. I haven't been able to reproduce that error locally.

Comment: @DavidG                                         user.email=woodyc40@gmail.com
user.name=AgentTroll
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://AgentTroll@github.com/AgentTroll/BukkitCommons.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: Glad to see you resolved the issue :-)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for your support, I used the PWD command you suggested to debug some directories :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the directory I was pushing under was different from the subtle directory name change of the push directory.

Answer (score 1):

First of, don't use `git add -A` without a pathspec. From the `git help add` page:

```
If no <pathspec> is given, the current version of Git defaults to "."; in other words, update
       all files in the current directory and its subdirectories. This default will change in a future
       version of Git, hence the form without <pathspec> should not be used.
```

So I advise you to change the command to `git add -A .` at the very least.

Lastly, about the specific problem, I can only suggest to check the value of $PWD to see where your build system's current directory is and try checking for ignored files and removed files.